# Automatically fill model object with data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have a model...

```
export class myModel{
  PropertyA: string;
  PropertyB: number;
  PropertyC: string;
  PropertyD: number;
  }
```

I have data that is returned...

```
  this.store.select(myDataStoreName)
  .subscribe(data=> {

  }
```

Data returned looks like...

```
"0: dataArray
    PropertyC: SomeText
    PropertyD: 33"
```

How do I automatically map and push this data returned into a new object created from the model?

I want to create a new object after getting data and update some values with whatever data has come back automatically in the object.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to create a new object after getting data and update some values with whatever data has come back automatically in the object.

Comment: I provided my answer to my best understanding of your question. If it does not help, put your complete user case. What you want to achieve and I might look into it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast your data to `myModel` and then assign it to a new object.

```
this.store.select(myDataStoreName)
    .subscribe((data: myModel[]) => {
      const newObject = data[0]; // creating new object.
     });
```